# Change jelastic container registry

Tags: jelastic

I want to change the registry connected to one of my Jelastic Environment's nodes. This is the procedure I used to create the environment and the nodes:

1. I set up a custom container in Jelastic.
2. I have chosen a registry link that points to my private docker registry
3. I created the environment and the node.

I now want to change the registry address, but I cannot find any option to do this.
I searched in the documentation (https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-containers-deployment/) but there is no mention of this option.

Is it possible to do this? how?

Comment: We have a registered improvement on this matter and its implementation will allow to perform such actions in future platform releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the URL of your registry without deleting the node or by asking your Jelastic's provider to do it on their side. Only Jelastic can do it by changing the URL registry on their database.